# Loop through ArrayList of objects C#

Tags: object, arraylist

I'm trying to loop through an **ArrayList of objects** of type (people) so i created two classes :

**Person.cs**

```
using System;

namespace GenericTypes
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    }
}
```

**People.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace GenericTypes
{
    public class People
    {
        public ArrayList GetNonGenericPeople()
        {
            var people = new ArrayList()
            {
                new Person() {FirstName = "Djerah", LastName = "Ahmed Rafik", Age = 23, DateTime = DateTime.Today},
                new Person() {FirstName = "Djerah", LastName = "Amjed Amir", Age = 11, DateTime = DateTime.Today},
                new Person() {FirstName = "Gadda", LastName = "Anoir", Age = 25, DateTime = DateTime.Today}

            };
            return people;
        }

        public  List<Person> GetGenericPeople()
        {
            var people = new List<Person>()
            {
                new Person() {FirstName = "Djerah", LastName = "Ahmed Rafik", Age = 23, DateTime = DateTime.Today},
                new Person() {FirstName = "Djerah", LastName = "Amjed Amir", Age = 11, DateTime = DateTime.Today},
                new Person() {FirstName = "Gadda", LastName = "Anoir", Age = 25, DateTime = DateTime.Today}

            };

            return people;
        }
    }
}
```

What i couldn't figure out is how to loop through **GetNonGenericPeople()** so can i output every object with it's properties

**program.cs**

```
namespace GenericTypes
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           var persons = new People();
            var p = persons.GetNonGenericPeople();

            foreach (var s in p)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `OfType<T>()` *Linq* which *filters out* `T` instances; another option is `Cast<T>()` which tries to *cast* each item (and throw exception if cast fails)

```
 foreach (var s in p.OfType<Person>()) {
   ...
 }
```

Comment: @D.AhmedRafik: you're welcome! However remember that `ArrayList` is *obsolete* class and `List<Person>` is a better choice for the collection.

Comment: One thing i didn't figure out is why we need to cast ArrayList to Generic List so we can access the properties of Person

Comment: `ArrayList` doesn't implement `IEnumerable<Person>` but `IEnumerable` only. It's possible that the `ArrayList` instance contians `string`, `object`, `Form` etc. items so we have either to *filter out* `Person` items via `OfType<Person>()` or *cast* items via `Cast<Person>()`